# How to normalize the coordinate without changing the object size?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, asymptote, metapost

The following MWE produces

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\psset
{
    unit=1cm,
    dipolestyle=zigzag,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](0,-4)(8,4)
    \resistor(0,0)(4,0){$R_1$}
    \resistor(4,0)(8,0){$R_2$}
    \resistor(4,0)(4,4){$R_3$}
    \resistor(4,0)(4,-4){$R_4$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I noticed that a resistor (among other components) needs a space of about 4 centimeter. Based on this fact, I want to normalize the coordinate from, for example, `\resistor(4,0)(4,-4){$R_4$}` to `\resistor(1,0)(1,-1){$R_4$}` by changing the unit `unit=4cm` as follows.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\psset
{
    unit=4cm,
    dipolestyle=zigzag,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](0,-1)(2,1)
    \resistor(0,0)(1,0){$R_1$}
    \resistor(1,0)(2,0){$R_2$}
    \resistor(1,0)(1,1){$R_3$}
    \resistor(1,0)(1,-1){$R_4$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the resistor itself also gets affected as follows.

[image]

## Question

Is there any way to normalize the grid without affecting the size of other drawn objects?

## Edit

I am also interested in other solutions (if any) with  TikZ, Metapost, Asymptote, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general *not* possible. Only with some tricky code ...

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\def\1{4}\def\2{8}
\psset{dipolestyle=zigzag}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](0,-\1)(\2,\1)
    \resistor(0,0)(\1,0){$R_1$}
    \resistor(\1,0)(\2,0){$R_2$}
    \resistor(\1,0)(\1,\1){$R_3$}
    \resistor(\1,0)(\1,-\1){$R_4$}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\let\Resistor\resistor
\def\resistor(#1,#2)(#3,#4){%
    \Resistor(\numexpr4*#1,\numexpr4*#2)%
            (\numexpr4*#3,\numexpr4*#4)}
\let\PSpicture\pspicture
\def\pspicture[#1](#2,#3)(#4,#5){%
    \PSpicture[#1](\numexpr4*#2,\numexpr4*#3)(\numexpr4*#4,\numexpr4*#5)}

\psset{dipolestyle=zigzag}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](0,-1)(2,1)
    \resistor(0,0)(1,0){$R_1$}
    \resistor(1,0)(2,0){$R_2$}
    \resistor(1,0)(1,1){$R_3$}
    \resistor(1,0)(1,-1){$R_4$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: and another tricky one added

Comment: Very good, could you apply the same trick for the  `pspicture` and the grid? :-)

Comment: see edited answer. This one needs always the optional argument for `pspicture` which can be, of course, empty: `\begin{pspicture[](...)`

Comment: Is it possible to change something like `Ox`, `Dx`, `dx`, etc of the grid?

Comment: Always with `\numexpr` or `\dimexpr` but that is always overkill .... ;-)